# C displays both (simple if-then)

Tags: c

I must be losing my mind :-(. I am not sure but I get yes and no displaying if I type in 2...

```
int main(void)
{
    int input;
    char yes[3] = "yes";
    char no[2] = "no";
    printf("Are you ok? Type in 1 for yes or 2 for no.\n");
    scanf("%d", &input);

    if (input == 1)
       printf("%s, I am\n.", yes);
    else
       printf("%s, I am not\n.", no);
    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: This question lacks one critical component... a question.

Comment: C strings are NULL terminated. That is, they have a zero value (`'\0'`) at the very end. You aren't leaving room for that NULL terminator, thus they don't have a well-defined end.

Comment: `yes` and `no` are not strings. You cannot use them with the printf `"%s"` conversion specifier

Answer (score 6):

```
char yes[3] = "yes";
```

You need `4` characters in your array.

```
 char no[2] = "no";
```

You need `3` characters in your array.

Otherwise C won't null terminate your arrays.

A better approach would be to let the size be handled automatically at build time:

```
char no[] = "no";
char yes[] = "yes";
```

Comment: Yep, and as its statically allocated, in most cases they'll be contained as "yesno" in memory, instead of "yes\0no\n", which is why he gets the yes and no displayed.